# Add/insert a new entry containing complex type in Entity Framework 7 Code first

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a new entry for my object model which has few complex type, using EF 7 code first. But it's not working and throwing exception.

Model:

```
public class Student 
{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public Address Address {get; set;} -> complex type
}

public class Address 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Location {get;set;}
}
```

Code first code:

```
class SchoolContext {
DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
DbSet<Address> Addresses {get; set;}

}

var context = new SchoolContext();

context.Students.Add(new Student { Id = 1, Name = "XYZ", Address = new Address { Id = 2, Location = "US" } } -> The add method has second parameter which says include dependent objects, and by default it is true.

context.SaveChanges();
```

This throws exception:

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Student_Address_AddressId\". The conflict occurred in database \"School\", table \"dbo.Address\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

This error I think means, the Address object does not exists in database, and if I add the address first and then Student, it works. But this is just too much code, as in my real application objects has many complex types.

Ideally this should work, but it does not.

Comment: Have you tried adding the address before the student?

Comment: Could you also post the actual class and not pseudo code? Not having the real code might be obscuring what is wrong. Are you using properties or fields? etc....

Comment: @MaximeRouiller-MVP, If i add the address object specifically before the student object, then it works fine. But what i think is, if i give a Student object to Entity, then entity should manage to add/update all the child objects. These are all properties in my actual Models.\

Comment: I agree. But could you post the actual code of your model or are you using fields?

Comment: Updated the code, i am only using properties. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Which version of the EntityFramework package are you using?

Comment: Version - "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this bug report](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2045), you should add item before.

It is considered `as-designed`. At least until RC2.